# ionic modal not working on real phone but working on browser

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an angular (16) application that I'm turning into an Android application using Ionic (version 7).

I have a page with a modal, in the browser it works fine, but when I try it on a real phone, the button does nothing and the modal won't even open.

Here's the parent component:

```
        <div *ngFor="let timeframe of match.timeframes; index as i" class="ion-padding-top">
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="openModal(i)">
                From: {{ convertDate(timeframe.start) | date : "short" }} to: {{ convertDate(timeframe.end) | date : "short" }}
            </ion-button>
        </div>
```

Basically every element that repeats in the ngFor cycle is a button that open a modal.
Here's the `openModal` function:

```
    async openModal(index: number) {
        if (!this.match?.timeframes) return;

        this.selectedTime = this.match.timeframes[index]?.start;
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: AcceptModal,
            componentProps: {
                timeframe: this.match.timeframes[index],
            },
        });

        modal.present();

        const { data, role } = await modal.onWillDismiss();

        if (role === "confirm") {
            this.accept(data);
        }
    }
```

This is the `AcceptModal` component:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicModule, ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Timeframe } from "../api/v1";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: "accept-modal",
    templateUrl: "./accept-modal.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./accept-modal.component.scss"],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [IonicModule, FormsModule],
})
export class AcceptModal {
    @Input() timeframe: Timeframe | null = null;
    selectedTimeframe: string | undefined = "";

    constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedTimeframe = this.timeframe?.start;
    }

    cancel() {
        return this.modalCtrl.dismiss(null, "cancel");
    }

    confirm() {
        return this.modalCtrl.dismiss(this.selectedTimeframe, "confirm");
    }
}
```

and the html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-button color="medium" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-button color="medium" (click)="confirm()">Confirm</ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="block">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-datetime confirm="" [(ngModel)]="selectedTimeframe" min={{timeframe?.start}}
            max={{timeframe?.end}}></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

So I kinda found a "solution"...if I add even an empty ion-modal element near the button that triggers the opening, my modal works as expected, so if I go from this code:

```
        <div *ngFor="let timeframe of match.timeframes; index as i" class="ion-padding-top">
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="openModal(i)">
                From: {{ convertDate(timeframe.start) | date : "short" }} to: {{ convertDate(timeframe.end) | date : "short" }}
            </ion-button>
        </div>
```

to this:

```
        <div *ngFor="let timeframe of match.timeframes; index as i" class="ion-padding-top">
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="openModal(i)">
                From: {{ convertDate(timeframe.start) | date : "short" }} to: {{ convertDate(timeframe.end) | date : "short" }}
            </ion-button>
            <ion-modal></ion-modal> <!-- Added this line here -->
        </div>
```

Then everything works. Doesn't feel like the correct way to fix this though...

Comment: What does the console say? there should be an error when inspect.

Comment: After going to "chrome://inspect/#devices" and inspect my phone, no errors show up in the console...

Comment: The HAS to be something showing in console. if you arent seeing anythin then you need to go thru the steps of debugging Example: place a console log in the modal method to see if its being called. if its not then you know your method is not being called. So check for any typos.

Answer (score 0):

The modal probably popped up before it received any data, because you have `modal.present()` as synchronous method call. So, my suggestion is to change your code a bit:

```
async openModal(index: number): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.match?.timeframes) return;

    this.selectedTime = this.match.timeframes[index]?.start;
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: AcceptModal,
        componentProps: {
            timeframe: this.match.timeframes[index],
        },
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(returnData => {
        if (returnData.role === "confirm") {
            this.accept(returnData.data);
        }
    }

    return await modal.present();

}
```

I think this way you're actually making it readable that there's some async stuff going on, and the progress of your code relies on data being sent and received at the right time.